# Show using Banach's fpt that the equation $f(x)=x^2+ \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{10+|x-t|^2}(f(t)+1)^2 \ dt, \ x \in [0,1],$ has a solution in $C([0,1])$.

Tags: banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

> Show using Banach's fixed point theorem that the equation $$f(x)=x^2+ \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{10+|x-t|^2}(f(t)+1)^2 \ dt, \ x \in [0,1],$$ has a solution in $C([0,1])$.

Define an operator $T: C([0,1])) \to C([0,1])$ as $$Tf(x) = x^2+ \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{10+|x-t|^2}(f(t)+1)^2 \ dt.$$

To show that $T$ is continuous we can consider $\|Tf(x) - Tg(x)\|$ for $f,g \in C([0,1])$.

One has that $$\left|x^2+ \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{10+|x-t|^2}(f(t)+1)^2 \ dt - \left( x^2+ \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{10+|y-t|^2}(g(t)+1)^2 \ dt \right) \right| \le \int_{0}^1 \left| \frac{1}{10+|x-t|^2}  \right|\left(|f(t)+1|^2 - |g(t)+1|^2  \right) \ dt$$

and considering the sup norm $$\int_{0}^1 \left| \frac{1}{10+|x-t|^2}  \right|\left(|f(t)+1|^2 - |g(t)+1|^2 \right) \ dt \le \int_{0}^1 \left| \frac{1}{10+|x-t|^2}  \right|\left(\|f^2-2f+1\|_\infty -\|g^2-2g+1\|_\infty \right) \ dt$$

$$\|Tf(x) - Tg(x)\|_\infty \le \|f^2-2f+1\|_\infty -\|g^2-2g+1\|_\infty \int_{0}^1 \left| \frac{1}{10+|x-t|^2}  \right|$$

but I cant get this to the form $$\|Tf(x)-Tg(x)\| \le C\|f-g\|_\infty.$$ The expression is already very nasty. Is there some tricks that can be applied here?

Comment: I think your inequalities are kinda wrong? The $(g(t) + 1)^2$ suddenly becomes a $(g(t) - 1)^2$, the $|.|$ should be around $(f(t+1))^2 - (g(t) + 1)^2$, and the same applies for when you take the sup norm?

Comment: Had a typo with the $(g(t) - 1)^2$. I've fixed it now. @BrunoB

Comment: Check your first inequality, after "One has that...". Plug $f=0, g=1$. The right-hand side becomes a negative number. This can't be as the left-hand side is nonnegative. That inequality is wrong.

Comment: There's still something wrong in how you used the traingular inequality: it should be: $$\left|x^2+ \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{10+|x-t|^2}(f(t)+1)^2 \ dt - \left( x^2+ \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{10+|y-t|^2}(g(t)+1)^2 \ dt \right) \right| \le \int_{0}^1 \left| \frac{1}{10+|x-t|^2}  \right|\left|(f(t)+1)^2 - (g(t)+1)^2  \right| \ dt$$ and then for the sup norm there's the same deal. It's not the end of the world, just be cautious when going too fast with absolute values and norms and such.

Comment: It is strange that you're asked to apply Banach fixed point theorem as $T$ is not a contraction mapping as you can see with the sequence of constant mappings $f_n = n$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Is it possible to show this without Banach's theorem?

Comment: You just have to restrict the space, with $X=\{f\in C([0,1]):\|f\|_\infty\le 2\}$ the condition for Banach should be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

On the space $\mathcal C([0,1])$, $T$ is not a contraction mapping as can be seen with the sequence $\{f_n = n\}$. However, on the closed ball $B$ centered on the always vanishing map of radius $2$, we have for any $x \in [0,1]$

$$\begin{aligned}
\lvert Tf(x)-Tg(x) \rvert &\le \frac{1}{10}\int_0^1 \lvert (f(t)+1)^2 - (g(t)+1)^2 \rvert dt\\
&= \frac{1}{10}\int_0^1 \lvert f(t)-g(t) \rvert \lvert f(t)+g(t) +2\rvert dt
\\&\le\left(\frac{1}{10}\int_0^1 6 dt\right) \lVert f-g \rVert_\infty = \frac{3}{5}\lVert f - g \rVert_\infty
\end{aligned}$$

Hence $\lVert Tf - Tg \rVert_\infty \le \frac{3}{5}\lVert f - g \rVert_\infty$ on $B$. This allows us to apply Banach fixed point theorem and to get the existence of a solution of the given equation.